# Show that $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} ka^k = an(a+1)^{n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, induction, binomial-coefficients

**Problem**:

Show that $\sum_{k=0}^{N} \binom{N}{k} ka^k = aN(a+1)^{N-1}$

**Attempt**:

I tried using induction but got stuck.

$N=0$ implies $\sum_{k=0}^{0} \binom{0}{k} ka^k = 0$

$N=1$ implies $\sum_{k=0}^{1} \binom{1}{k} ka^k = a = a(1)(a+1)^{1-1}$

$N=2$ implies $\sum_{k=0}^{2} \binom{2}{k} ka^k = 2a(a+1)^{2-1}$

Assume that for $N=n$, $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} ka^k = na(a+1)^{n-1}$. Then, for $N=n+1$, we find

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{k} ka^k = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \left(\binom{n}{k-1}+\binom{n}{k}\right) ka^k$$

Splitting up the sum on the right gives

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{n}{k-1}ka^k + \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}ka^k + \binom{n}{n+1}ka^k$$

and since $\binom{n}{n+1}=0$, we have

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{k} ka^k = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{n}{k-1}ka^k + an(a+1)^{n-1}$$

and this is where I'm stuck. If we look at it from the other direction, we have

$$(n+1)a(a+1)^{n+1-1} = (n+1)a(a+1)^n = na(a+1)^n + a(a+1)$$

But I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: More direct approach: Use $k\binom{N}{k}=N\binom{N-1}{k-1}.$

Comment: I will try, thank you! @ThomasAndrews

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like Thomas Andrews suggested, we can use the fact that
$$
k\binom{n}{k}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}.
$$
We have
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}ka^k&=\sum_{k=0}^nn\binom{n-1}{k-1}a^k\\
&=n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n-1}{k-1}a^k \ \ \ \ \ \ (\text{setting}\ \ell=k-1),\\
&=n\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{\ell}a^{\ell +1}\\
&=na\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{\ell}a^{\ell}\ \ \ \ \ \ (\text{by the Binomial Theorem}),\\
&=na(a+1)^{n-1}.
\end{align}

Comment: Right, but you should mention why the new terms go from $k=1$ rather than $k=0$ when you switch variables...

Answer (score 4):

By Binomial theoren:

$$(1+a)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} a^k$$
Differentiate w.r.t. $a$, to get
$$n(1+a)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} k {n \choose k} a^{k-1}$$
Multiply by $a$ both side to get the result.

Comment: Brilliant. Wish I had thought of this!

Answer (score 1):

$$S=\sum_{k=0}^{n} k {n \choose k} a^k =\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!} a^k= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n (n-1)!}{(k-1)! (n-k)!}=n\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n-1 \choose k-1} a^k$$
Let $k-1=p$, then
$$S=n\sum_{p=-1}^{n-1} {n-1 \choose p} a^{p+1}=na\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} {n-1 \choose p} a^p=na(1+a)^{n-1}.$$
Note that ${m \choose -n}=0$, where $n,m$ are positive integers.